# \b modifier won't work for Unicode characters

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to replace an exact word using `preg_replace` by `\b` modifier as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078477/replace-exact-match-in-php) question.

But it seems that won't work for Unicode characters such as Persian and Arabic. This example works:

```
preg_replace('/(\bto\b|\bis\b)/i', '', 'go to test if var is set using isset')
```

But this one won't work:

```
preg_replace('/(\bاز\b|\bبه\b)/i', '', 'راه مدرسه به خونه از اونجا میگذره')
```

Is there a way to get the required result, splitting on word boundaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it myself, have to use `\u` modifier simply as

```
preg_replace('/(\bاز\b|\bبه\b)/iu', '', 'راه مدرسه به خونه از اونجا میگذره')
```